# Make wrapping flex-row start the third row in a new column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For a current client-project of mine I was asked to showcase the team of around 20 people. It will, of course, be a dynamic page and the client will be able to add and remove people from this list.

Each person has their own div, containing a profile-picture, a heading with the name and a paragraph with a short description. **The div for a person has a fixed size.**

What I want to do is this: I created a wrapper for all teammember-divs and added the properties `display: flex;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;`. I modified margins and paddings so that a row holds five teammember-divs before it wraps into the next one. This means 10 people equal exactly two full rows. The eleventh person is now supposed to start a second set of 2*5 people, positioned on the right side of the first set. Here are some examples what it would look like:

```
05 people: 1 row with 5
07 people: 2 rows, first 5, second 2
10 people: 2 rows with 5 each
11 people: 2 rows, first 6, second 5
14 people: 2 rows, first 9, second 5
20 people: 2 rows, with 10 each
23 people: 2 rows, first 13, second 10
```

The second set of 2*5 people should extend the wrapper horizontally so that the two rows are scrollable. Later a script will be added to replace the ugly scrollbar with arrows to browse left and right through the sets of 2*5 team members.

**The Problem:** Currently, I have no idea how to position the "third row" on the right side of the first row (and so on).

Does anyone have an idea on this problem? Thanks in advance for tips and advice!

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKQvjV

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or codepen with your code?

Comment: Sure, give me a second...

Comment: Are you able to change the HTML structure?

Comment: I am, I wrote the plugin myself that is generating the HTML code from WordPress user-list. But I would prefer not to add DOM for this...

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/ZQrJBo

Comment: Almost. Like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyQMdM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately breaking to a new column won't work as you want with `flex`. You'll need to slightly alter your HTML structure to create 2 columns. Here's [your CodePen](http://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/ZQrJBo) showing the result.

```
.team {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.member {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

<div class="team">
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
</div>
<div class="team">
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
  <div class="member"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that would obviously work. But I thought there would be a more "dynamic" solution for this to make it responsive later on (make one row contain two people for small screens, for example)...

Thanks anyway! I think I will do it this way.

Comment: This could be made responsive still. For example, on smaller screens the columns would stack, and the `flex` children could take up 50% so you would have 2 per row. But to make it break into columns the way you want you'll need to structure it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try quantity queries and create rules for these numbers you mention.

A good link to learn about quantity queries is in A List Apart: [quantity queries](http://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css) 
And somebody even build a builder to help in the task: [quantityqueries.com](http://www.quantityqueries.com/)

**EDIT:**

Now I saw your codepen. instead of justify-content: center, use justify-content: flex-end; That will right-align the items in you row.

Comment: That is a good starting point, I didn't think of quantity queries. But even then; how to tell flex to start a "new column" after a specific element?

Comment: @JonathanWeber You mean "a new row"? You can't really do it cross browser with flex. there are rules like break-before or break-after but they are not well supported. The only way I see is to limit the width of each row.